# Extending TcpClient class in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing server application and I want to do something like this:

```
class MyClient : TcpClient
{        
    public StreamReader Reader { get; }
    public StreamWriter Writer { get; }
    public MyClient()
    {
          Reader = new StreamReader(this.GetStream());
          Writer = new StreamWriter(this.GetStream());           
    }       
}
```

Then I want to listen to an incoming connection and create `MyClient` object:

```
TcpListener listener= new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(Constants.IpAddress), Constants.Port);
MyClient client = (MyClient)listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

I know that I cant downcast like this (`TcpClient` is not `MyClient`).
But `MyClient` Is `TcpClient`, so what do I need to do, to accomplish such scenario?
create a `MyClient` constructor that takes `TcpClient` argument and invokes base `TcpClient` class constructor. I want  `MyClient` to be a `TcpClient` instead of having `TcpClient` property. Or maybe Socket class will be better in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing

```
(MyClient)listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

will never work, whatever you do, because it always return regular `TcpClient` (and this method is not virtual in `TcpListener` so you cannot change that). Same story with `AcceptSocket`. You can create a proxy class which will not inherit from `TcpClient` but will implement all the same public members and proxy their implementation to real `TcpClient` you store in private field and pass to constructor. However then you cannot pass that class to any method that expects regular `TcpClient`.

Implementation of `AcceptTcpClient` creates `TcpClient` using constructor which accepts socket, however this constructor is internal so you cannot use this way.

Another option that comes to mind is:

```
class MyClient : TcpClient
{
    public StreamReader Reader { get; }
    public StreamWriter Writer { get; }
    public MyClient(Socket acceptedSocket)
    {
        this.Client.Dispose();
        this.Client = acceptedSocket;
        this.Active = true;
        Reader = new StreamReader(this.GetStream());
        Writer = new StreamWriter(this.GetStream());
    }
}
```

And then pass socket from `AcceptSocket` to constructor. But I don't like it, because default constructor of `TcpClient` will be called, which creates new socket (which is disposed at the first line of constructor above).

Comment: I do not like this default constructor either, but it is still a pretty good solution to my problem. Thank you :)
P.S Is setting the Active property necessary?

Comment: @KarolŻurowski yes it is.